# Why Use a Remote Linux Desktop for Development?

Tags: linux, ssh, development-environment, remote-server, remote-desktop

I've recently started my first job as a developer. They've assigned me a MacBook Pro, but they also set me up with a Linux desktop. I've set up my SSH keys to make a connection to the remote desktop and was instructed on how to clone repositories on remote desktop.

**What is the purpose of having to SSH into a remote desktop to do development work?** What are the main pros and cons?

Answer (score 4):

Few of the reasons I can think of

1. **Security** : So that the production code which your company owns does not reside in your laptop.
2. **Safety** : The Linux OS you ssh'ed into is probably running on a server with all kinds of redundancy and replication configured.
3. **Central build environment** : Building custom code usually requires specific libraries and have specific dependencies. If you want to build and develope in your laptop, and just like you if all employees do, then those dependencies and libraries have to be installed in everyone's laptop OS.

Comment: These reasons also make me think the better question would be "Why did my employer put a physical machine on my desk instead of  providing a virtual machine hosted on some other server?"